# Gmail Add-on PopToRoot not clearing history

Tags: gmail-addons

For a GMail add-on, I'm finding that "popToRoot()" is not working as expected. When this is called from within a universal action, the user is sent to the root, but there is a "back" arrow available for them to return to the previous card.

From the docs, that should not be happening. Any suggestions?

Sample code:

`return CardService
        .newActionResponseBuilder()
        .setNavigation(
           CardService
               .newNavigation()
               .popToRoot()
               .updateCard(makeRootCard(messageId)))
        .build();`

where `makeRootCard` creates and returns a built card.

Comment: I could not reproduce the issue you are facing. Are you still facing the issue, Glen?

Comment: Yes. I've not found any way to get to the root and not have a "Back" arrow still showing.

Comment: can you share your code ? I might be able to help.

Comment: @HariBalaji Thanks. Sample code added.

Answer (score 0):

This problem occurred when trying to log out from a non-Google authentication. It turns out that the `makeRootCard()` method was returning an `AuthorizationException` as per the normal authorization flow. I had to make few workarounds to avoid that and give the `updateCard` method a raw card to work with.